# Mouseleave or different function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I created a form that I am wanting to only appear if the user goes to leave the site. I searched to find a function for this and the closest one I could find was `mouseleave`.

It works well - at least on a desktop (haven't checked mobile yet) except there is one issue. I want the popup to appear only once. Right now it appears every time the mouse goes outside the body.

The perfect solution would not use body, instead it would detect when the user goes to the browser tabs/search bar in the browser. I wasn't sure what to put, so body seemed like a decent starting point.

Is there also a way to limit this to working one time?

```js
$('body').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#specialPop').fadeIn(350);
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
  var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
  $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
  $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#specialPop {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 color: #FFF;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999999;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 display: none;
}
.popSpecialClose {
 position: absolute;
 right: 40px;
 top: 20px;
 width: 33px;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="specialPop" data-popup="popSpecial">
 <a class="popSpecialClose" data-popup-close="popSpecial" href="#">
  Close
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('window').on('unload',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Do your stuff
  });
```

Please note that most of the browser will ignore that practice because it's way too intrusive for the user

Comment: Are you referring to the method you provided or the one I was using?

Comment: The one I provided, don't worry :) yours is fine, but there's many way to leave the window with the mouse (even when just chilling), basically, the scroll is out of the scope. Maybe aim at 'window' instead of 'body'? If I had to make it your way, I'd simply add a 100% width 4px height DIV at the very top of the page (position absolute, top:0) and when the mouse go over it, I do the stuff with the fadein() etc